# Bootstrap 4 - How to put another nav selection on top and collapse into one

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

inserting another selection above my existing `<nav>`
here's what i want to happen.[image]

Here's my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rLc588mu/

Thank you!

Comment: create your own or use breadcrumb as a nav if you are really lazy guy https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/

Comment: Do you have to use v4 alpha 3? It's way behind 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you looking for additional links above your nav.

**To Bring top right:**
Place another div or nav and add the Bootstrap specific class to it

```
float-right
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunkneworld/90usgqda/9/)

Comment: yeah i tried that but it wont float right. i'm using bootstrap alpha. kindly check my code if you have time.thanks . i'll give this a try later. Thanks!

Comment: float right working fine, I have just updated the link in above example. try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you!, i guess the key was <div style="clear:both;"></div> after some tweaking i finally go it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand align-self-end" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column justify-content-between align-items-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-self-end">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-self-start">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Made Use Of `align-self` classes on `ul` and `flex-column` class on '`navbar-collapse`' div

[Link For Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/m9xw3yaj/1/)

Comment: i'll try this , btw is this applicable in bootstrap 4alpha cause that's what i've been using. thank you

Comment: i have used bootstrap v4.0 not the alpha. once give a try with B.v4.alpha.